# Loop through specific columns and setting value

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script but it works pretty slow and Im trying to see if I could make it work faster by possibly making it loop through the columns 10,12,15,17,20,22,25,27,30,32,35,37,40,42,45,47,50,52,55,57 instead of writing an if statement for each column. The way I currently have it works but it's slow and looks like this

```
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Student Data-NEA" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() == 'P') { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue("P- N/A");
    }

    if( r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == 'P') { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue("P- N/A");
    }

    if( r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == 'P') { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue("P- N/A");
    }
    if( r.getColumn() == 17 && r.getValue() == 'P') { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      //if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue("P- N/A");
    }
Etc.
```

What it does is it looks at a column and if there is a P then it offsets 1 column and pastes a P- N/A. Could someone help making the script shorter so it can run faster? Thank you.

Comment: Based on your comment in the existing answer. You want that if a cell was edited using an onEdit() trigger, you want to check if that cell is in a particular column listed in the post description. Then check its value and assign appropriate value on its offset 1 column? is my understanding correct?

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample sheet to check the execution time in your side? [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getValues(range)`. This way you get an array. You can process this array and then use `setValues(range)` to fill all cells in the range at once with values of the array. It will work much faster.

Probably something like this:

```
function main() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() != "Student Data-NEA") return;

  var r          = s.getActiveCell();             // current cell
  var row        = r.getRow();                    // index of current row
  var row_range  = s.getRange("A"+row+":Z"+row);  // get range of the row
  var row_values = row_range.getValues().flat();  // get array [cell, cell, cell]
  var value      = "P- N/A";

  // change the array (not the sheet)
  if (row_values[9]  == "P") row_values[10] = value;
  if (row_values[11] == "P") row_values[12] = value;
  if (row_values[14] == "P") row_values[15] = value;
  if (row_values[16] == "P") row_values[17] = value;
  
  // change the sheet
  row_range.setValues([row_values]); // set all values for the row at once
}
```

[image]

If your conditions all the same, you can loop through list of columns this way:

```
  var condition  = "P";
  var columns    = [9, 11, 14, 16];

  for (var col of columns) {
    if (row_values[col] == condition) row_values[col+1] = value;
  }

  // instead of this
  // if (row_values[9]  == "P") row_values[10] = value;
  // if (row_values[11] == "P") row_values[12] = value;
  // if (row_values[14] == "P") row_values[15] = value;
  // if (row_values[16] == "P") row_values[17] = value;
```

**Update**

I don't know why I do it, since the author of the question still provided almost no information about what he does with the table and we have no sample of the table, etc. But whatever:

If you need to change next cell to "P- N/A" (do you need it? I still have no idea) in some columns if edited cell contains "P", here is a script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() != "Student Data-NEA") return;

  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  var row = e.range.rowStart;

  var range = s.getRange(row,col,1,2);
  var range_array = range.getValues();

  var cell_value = range_array[0][0];
  var next_cell_value = "P- N/A";

  var cols = [10, 12, 15, 17];

  if (cell_value == "P" && cols.includes(col)) {
    range_array[0][1] = next_cell_value;
    range.setValues(range_array);
  }

}
```

But actually it can be done much easier and faster with standard Excel-like function (example for the cell "K1"):

```
=IF(EQ(J1,"P"),"P- N/A","")
```

Just populate with this function the columns K, M, P, R...

Comment: Khritich How would I change it to do that but when the P is inserted like on edit rather than all at once?

Comment: Describe exactly what you're doing with table and what do you expect from the script? If you change a cell, script can check the value of current cell and if the value == "P" it can change value in the cell in next column. In this workflow there is no way to make the script to work faster. It just checks one cell and set another cell. But if you want to change many cells, it can be faster via `setValues()`